# How to set value to variable of class and display it?

Tags: php, class

In my project, I have defined a Test class.

Only __construct function in this class, Here is code of Test class:

```
<?php
namespace model;
public  class Test  {
private $db;
protected $fields;
public $variables;

public function __construct($data = array()) {
    if ($this->fields && $data) {
        foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
            if (!in_array($k, $this->fields)) {
                unset($data[$k]);
            }
        }
     }
    $this->variables  = $data;
}

}
```

Now I want to use this class, Here is my html code:

```
<body style="height:100%" >
<?php 
include "o1ws1v/class/model/Test.php";//include class file
$test_model = new \model\Test();

$test_model->xie="zuo";
echo    $test_model->xie;
?>
</body>
```

But unlucky, It works fail. Nothing is showed in console.

I have tested:

```
var_dump($test_model);
```

It also did nothing .

I want to assign  value to a variable of Test class and display it.

Who can help me?

Comment: I get `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file in ...` when running this code. Change `public class` to only `class` and your code should work

Comment: @kerbholz sounds like the solution and answer to me. Post it as an answer for some rep! (and so the OP can close)

Comment: @kerbholz, It works OK! Thankyou. But why class can not be public? In Java, class can be defined to public

Comment: In PHP public and private only apply to properties and functions, classes are all public.

Comment: Barmar answered that already, here's some more [info on Classes and Objects in PHP](https://secure.php.net/language.oop5)

Comment: A general remark: this looksmlike you are setting object properties that are not definend in the class... Though this is actually possible in php it is kind of bad practice since it contradicts the basic ideas behind OOP. So unless you have _very_ specific situations you really should rethink this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code as it is you'll get an error

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC),
>   expecting end of file in ...

Remove the `public` keyword from your `Test` class:

```
<?php

namespace model;

class Test  {
    private $db;
    protected $fields;
    public $variables;

    public function __construct($data = array()) {
        if ($this->fields && $data) {
            foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
                if (!in_array($k, $this->fields)) {
                    unset($data[$k]);
                }
            }
        }
        $this->variables  = $data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change public class to only class and this portion of code should be working.

```
<?php
namespace model;
class Test  {
private $db;
protected $fields;
public $variables;

public function __construct($data = array()) {
    if ($this->fields && $data) {
        foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
            if (!in_array($k, $this->fields)) {
                unset($data[$k]);
            }
        }
     }
    $this->variables  = $data;
}

}
```